# Find Matrix From Given Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I have been stuck on this problem for days now and any help is appreciated.

Express the $\mathrm{span}(E)$, which is the the two vectors below, as a kernel of a $3×3$ matrix:

\begin{pmatrix} 
2\\3\\-5\ \end
{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -4 \\-5 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix}

Comment: @MichaelUlrich Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Since the rank of the matrix is 1, it suffices to find a row vector $r=(a,b,c)$ such that

- $r\cdot v_1=0$
- $r\cdot v_2=0$

and use this row vector for all the rows of the matrix.

Note that we can simplify the derivation by combining the vectors, for example as follow

$$v_3=2v_1+v_2=\begin{pmatrix} 
0\\1\\-2\ \end
{pmatrix}$$

$$v_4=v_1-3v_3=\begin{pmatrix} 
2\\0\\1\ \end
{pmatrix}$$

and then use $v_3$ and $v_4$ which allow to find directly a solution that is

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1&-4&-2\\1&-4&-2\\1&-4&-2\ \end
{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I’d use the same method you used to construct the oblique reflection in another answer: find a basis in which the matrix is $\operatorname{diag}(1,0,0)$. Two of the basis vectors are already given.

Comment: @amd Yes I thought about that but my aim was to give a simpler solution here. Thanks anyway for the hint, recombine the  vector the solution seems quite simple.

Comment: @gimusi I explained it poorly, but what I am asking is that once you take the kernel of the matrix, it will be equal to that of the vectors that are given, so that **ker(A) = {(2, 3, -5), (-4, -5, 8)}**  I apologize if I created a confusion, or most likely I am failing to understand your answer

Comment: What is the kernel of the matrix with rows (1,-4,-2)?

Answer (score 1):

Hints . . .

- Let $u = \langle{2,3,-5}\rangle$, and let $v=\langle{-4,-5,-8}\rangle$.$\\[4pt]$

  Are the vectors $u,v$ linearly independent?$\\[4pt]$

  What is the dimension of the span of $\{u,v\}$?$\\[4pt]$

  Let $w$ be a nonzero vector such that $w$ is orthogonal to both $u$ and $v$. For example, you can take $w=u{\,\times\,}v$.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $A$ be the $3{\,\times\,}3$ matrix with all rows equal to $w$.$\\[4pt]$

  What can you say about $Au$?$\\[4pt]$

  What can you say about $Av$?$\\[4pt]$

  For $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, what can you say about $A(au+bv)$?$\\[4pt]$

  What is the rank of $A$?$\\[4pt]$

  What is the dimension of the kernel of $A$?$\\[4pt]$

  How does the kernel of $A$ relate to the span of $\{u,v\}$?